# Flutter Google Maps Markers flicker

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I implemented a Google Map via the pub package "google_maps_flutter 2.0.6" into my Android App.
Also I added two markers. The map is working fine, but the **two markers flicker** every now and then...

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class RouteMapScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  LatLng _center = LatLng(49.975015, 9.146784);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
        key: Key("SingleRoute"),
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        markers: {
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId("1"),
            position: LatLng(49.9775, 9.1432),
          ),
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId("2"),
            position: LatLng(49.9785, 9.1432),
          )
        },
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: _center,
          zoom: 15.0,
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: this actually is a bug, please follow this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85907 for updates on this matter.

Comment: It is true, I am indeed using another map in the app... Thanks for your answer!